# Analysis of Prim's Algorithm

Tags: graph-algorithm

Can anyone explain why we use or what's the importance of using the key array(i.e key[])
in PRIM'S ALGORITHM which deals with the minimum spanning tree problem.

```
PRIM_MST(G,W,R)//G->graph,W->weighted matrix,R->root vertex
-------------------------

for v<-v[G]
    key[v]<-infinity
    pred[v]<-NIL     //pred[]-->predecessor array
key[v]=0
Q<-v[G]              //Q-->priority queue
while Q!=NULL
     u<-EXTRACT_MIN(Q)
      for v<-adj[u]   //adj[]--> adjacency list matrix
           if v belongs to Q && w(Q,v)<key[v]
                 pred[v]<-u,key[v]<-w(u,v)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a key[] in PRIM's algorithm. Probably you are referring to an implementation example.

Comment: Please post the code you're referring to.

Comment: @SteveP. I've posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Key is basically the value on the edge that led to the particular vertex in the graph during the construction of MST

on arriving on a vertex during the algorithm, it checks for the minimum weighted edge connecting the set A(the set of vertices already traversed) and set B(the set of edges not yet traversed). It follows this minimum edge and puts the key of the newly arrived vertex(the one reached after following this min edge) as the weight of this minimum edge